# recursive function in cpp gives error "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

Tags: c++, recursion, segmentation-fault

what I'm trying to do is to return the sum of all numbers bellow or equal to a number like n, that are multiples of 3 or 5, i tried to do this in c++ with a recursive function:

```
#include <iostream>

int getsum(int n);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    std::cout<<getsum(10);
    
    return 0;
}

int getsum(int n){

    if(n%3==0 || n%5==0)
        return n+getsum(n-1);
    if(n==0) 
        return 0;
    else
    {
        return getsum(n-1);
    }
    
}
```

then when i try to run this code i get segmentation fault error:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

is there a problem in my recursive function?

*OS:Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: this should return 33 for n=10

Comment: Looks like you are programming in the C++ language and not C.  The C language doesn't have the `iostream` header file, nor does it have `std::cout`.  I recommend you update your language tags as appropriate.

Comment: `0 % 3` is `0`.

Comment: What's 0 % 3? What's 0 % 5? Move your base case to the top. Not a good use case for recursion in any event.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews yes this is  c++ code, thanks for reminding

Comment: Make `if(n == 0)` the first thing.

Comment: @user3386109 oh i got it, thanks!

Comment: Stepping through this function a few times with the debugger that should have come with your development environment would shown you what was happening very, very quickly. Don't waste time. Learn to use the debugger.

Comment: @user4581301 actually i used the g++ in terminal with no debugging

Comment: g++ almost always ships with gdb, and when it doesn't, it's an easy add-on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that when `n` reaches zero, you get into the block.

```
if(n%3==0 || n%5==0)
    return n+getsum(n-1);
```

Once `n` reaches a negative number, the recursive call keeps going for ever. That causes stack overflow.

You should move the check against zero as the first thing.

```
int getsum(int n)
{
   std::cout << "n: " << n << std::endl;

   if(n==0) 
   {
      return 0;
   }
   if(n%3==0 || n%5==0)
   {
      return n+getsum(n-1);
   }
   else
   {
      return getsum(n-1);
   }
}
```

The additional `std::cout <<`  line will help you track the flow of calls as a diagnostic tool.